# How to start Tomcat in debug mode and print to console?

Tags: tomcat

normally i start tomcat just with this command:

```
./catalina.sh run
```

And if i need to debug code i use:

```
./catalina.sh jpda start
```

This works fine so far. But if i use the second command the log is not displayed in the console. I would like to run tomcat in debug mode and see the log file in the console. Currently i always need to change between these 2 modes when needed.

This question seems quite easy, but i did not manage to find something appropriate on stackoverflow or google :-/

Thanks for your help! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to view the log by using something like:

```
tail -f /var/log/tomcat6/catalina.out
```

(your system's path may vary.)

Answer (score 2):

> ./catalina jpda run

that might also work

Answer (score 0):

tomcat also have log directory in it.you can tail it by using.

> tail -f /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/logs/catalina.out